# How to fill tinymce context menu and submenu dynamically?

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I have a tinymce editor where I'm using context menu to perform some function, but the submenus have to be loaded dynamically based on response from ajax which is invoked on `onmouseenter` event. I have created a running fiddle example [here](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/YIfaab). Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE does not support dynamically modifying the toolbars or menus after the editor is initialized on the page.

Comment: Calculate all of that info on page load but before you init the editor - then init the editor once you have that data.

Comment: Thank you @Michael